# angular-bootstrap 0.12.0 navbar dropdown not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using AngularJS 1.3.10 along with Bootstrap 3.3.2 and angular-ui-bootstrap 0.12.0.  I am also using the Angular ui-router for routing.  It seems like the navbar dropdown does not work in 0.12.0.  Dropping back to 0.11.0 works.
Here is the code that I am using (partial):

```html
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-controller="searchController">
     <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
             <a ui-sref="dashboard" class="navbar-brand">My Application</a>
         </div>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="navCollapsed" >
             <li ><a ui-sref="dashboard" ng-click="navCollapsed = true"><i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
             <li ><a ui-sref="topmenu1" ng-click="navCollapsed = true"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Top Menu 1</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                 <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <li><a ui-sref="item1">Item 1</a></li>
                  <li><a ui-sref="item2">Item 2</a></li>
                  <li><a ui-sref="item3">Item 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: And let me stress that the above code works fine in 0.10.0 and 0.11.0 of angular-ui-bootstrap.  It stops working in 0.12.0, so I am wondering if there is an issue in 0.12.0 that has caused this to stop working.  I have rolled my code back to use 0.11.0, but wanted to post the question in case there is a bug.

Answer (score 5):

They added a `uib-dropdown` and `uib-dropdown-toggle` directive that you must use now. Here's your updated code snippet:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-controller="searchController">
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a ui-sref="dashboard" class="navbar-brand">My Application</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="navCollapsed" >
            <li ><a ui-sref="dashboard" ng-click="navCollapsed = true"><i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li ><a ui-sref="topmenu1" ng-click="navCollapsed = true"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Top Menu 1</a></li>
            <!-- Notice the dropdown directive -->
            <li class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
                <!-- Notice the dropdown-toggle directive -->
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" uib-dropdown-toggle>Dropdown
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a ui-sref="item1">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a ui-sref="item2">Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a ui-sref="item3">Item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see some examples at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for. Thanks! As an update, use `uib-dropdown` and `uib-dropdown-toggle` now.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are doing it wrong. What you are using is for Bootstrap and not UI-Bootstrap. Here is an example:

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="HeaderCtrl" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/home">Project Title</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" collapse="navCollapsed" ng-click="navCollapsed=true">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/home') }"><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/about') }"><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('controllers.header', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller("HeaderCtrl", function($scope, $location) {

    $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
        var active = (viewLocation === $location.path());
        return active;
    };

});
```

Have a look at this project: [Angular Project Template](https://github.com/ekonstantinidis/angular-project-template/). It's Angular 1.3, Bootstrap and UI Bootstrap. Exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Make sure everything is installed properly and that there are no errors in the console.

Comment: That example is for collapsing the entire menu.  I am simply trying to add a dropdown menu item to the top navbar.  I will add the entire menu code to explain further.

Comment: The project's code fully satisfied my 2 days research, man you you saved my mental health!

Comment: @Stephane.P Glad it helped!